# SqlDataReader does not have the correct columns count

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I'm designing a website using asp.net (webforms) and C#. I have a table which has 23 columns.

In the code below, `reader` is a `SqlDataReader` and command is a `SqlCommand` object. I'm using the following code to output query result from it:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE device_level='" + ACCESS_LVL + "'" + "ORDER BY device_name";
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

and then I loop through it using

```
while(reader.Read());
```

to output the results.

However accessing some columns causes an index out of range exception (indexes above 17). My table has 23 columns but `reader.FieldCount` returns only 18.

This issue is not happening on my local machine when debugging the code. It only happens when I upload the project to my web server.

Using mylittleadmin database management panel (installed on the remote server) I can see all of the 23 columns.

Comment: Please learn to parametrise your SQL. `"WHERE device_level='" + ACCESS_LVL + "'"` is wide open to injection and needs to be changed ASAP.

Comment: You should also not use `SELECT *`, instead list the columns that you expect explicitly

Comment: To follow along with what @Rango says, you should really explicitly call out what columns you want to select.  It's not unusual for "identical" tables in different environments (Local, DEV, QA, PROD, for example) to have their columns in different orders, or, at times, to have a differing number of columns.  This may be your case.  What is _"mylittleadmin database management"_?  Have you tried running the same query with SSMS against the same db instance?  Have you looked to see what columns you are missing?  Do their names "ring a bell"?

Comment: @Rango i also changed my query to do that. causes an error: Invalid column name sensor1last

Comment: Well that is a pretty clear indication that your two databases do not have the same columns in those tables.

Comment: @Flydog57 myLittleAdmin for SQL Server, web-based MS SQL administration tool. google it

Comment: @SeanLange i'm querying data from a single table and a single database

Comment: You can't possibly query the same table on the same database  using the same query and get different columns.

Comment: @SeanLange you can if you query it as two different logins, and there are login-specific objects (meaning: objects in two different schemas - maybe `abolfa.devices` and `dbo.devices`)

Comment: @MarcGravell true. Or if one login has permission to a column that the other doesn't (since they are using select *). But I highly doubt that is the situation here. It is almost certainly what you and I both stated, that the schemas of that table are different.

Comment: @SeanLange I *think* that just gives you a permission denied error, not a different column count - but I'm working from memory here

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah I don't do anything with column level permission either, and certainly not select * so I don't recall either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL server is going to be correct here. If `SELECT * FROM devices ...` returns 18 columns, then: the `devices` object on the database being connected to: *has 18 columns*. It sounds like you've let your schemas diverge between different environments / databases. Alternatively: it is possible that you have multiple logins, and login-specific objects (i.e. objects in two different database schemas in the same database), so: when you query it *as you* you see *one* object as `devices` - and when you query it *as the application account* you see a *different* object. Typically, this would be `dbo.devices` vs `abolfa.devices` (for example).